# Destination array was not long enough Error. How to solve it?

Tags: c#, arrays

I was tried to implement this code in one my application
https://gist.github.com/dampee/724a30d8f377ceeb05f4

Its a lorem ipsum builder.
But when I run the app at the constructer part which is

```
 public LoremIpsumBuilder()
        {

            MatchCollection matches = WordSplitter.Matches(Original);
            matches.CopyTo(_arrOriginal.ToArray(), 0);

        }
```

it shows an error in the following line of code.

```
   matches.CopyTo(_arrOriginal.ToArray(), 0);
```

> "System.ArgumentException: 'Destination array was not long enough.
> Check the destination index, length, and the array's lower bounds.
> (Parameter 'destinationArray')'""

What is the issue here?

Comment: The line `matches.CopyTo(_arrOriginal.ToArray(), 0);` copies data into a temporary array and will not affect the data in `_arrOriginal` regardless of the size of the arrays, The `.ToArray()` often creates a copy of the underlying array.

Comment: What is `_arrOriginal`, how is it defined and how is it initialized?

Comment: Clearly destination array is not long enough (as you obviously read from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copyto?view=net-7.0#system-array-copyto(system-array-system-int32))... But it is not possibly to suggest how to fix that as code make no sense at all. Explaining what you wanted to achieve with copying matches to (discarded) result of `ToArray` call would help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the `_arrOriginal` list from the regex matches with

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="LoremIpsumBuilder"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public LoremIpsumBuilder()
    {
        MatchCollection matches = WordSplitter.Matches(Original);
        _arrOriginal = matches.OfType<string>().ToList();
    }
```

your clue is that `matches.CopyTo(Array, int)` expects an array to copy to, and `_arrOriginal` is a `List<string>` which is not an array. So to make it work you generated a copy of `_arrOriginal` as a destination, but this resulted in an empty array.